# Simultaneously fill missing values in related columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns State and Code, with missing values in each.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Alabama', 'AL'], ['Alaska', 'AK'], ['Arizona', 'AZ'], ['Arkansas', 'AR'], ['Iowa','IA'],['Hawaii','HI'], ['Idaho', 'ID'], ['Alabama', ''], ['', 'IA'], ['Alaska',''], ['', 'AZ']], columns=['State', 'Code'])
```

Missing values

```
    State   Code
7   Alabama     
8             IA
9   Alaska  
10            AZ
```

What I've tried

```
state_code_dict = {
    'Alabama': 'AL',
    'Alaska': 'AK',
    'Arizona': 'AZ',
    'Arkansas': 'AR',
    'Iowa':'IA',
    'Hawaii':'HI',
    'Idaho': 'ID',    
}

def state_code(x):
    if (x['Code'] == ''):
        return state_code_dict[x['State']]
    else:
        return x['Code']

df['Code'] = df.apply(lambda x: state_code(x), axis=1)
```

This sets the missing values in Code. I need to update this function for setting State as well. I'm looking to simplify this.

Required output

```
    State   Code
7   Alabama   AL
8   Iowa      IA
9   Alaska    AK
10  Arizona   AZ
```

Comment: I am sure I saw the seems question before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `map` to first map codes and then states, using boolean masking to just assign values when you have empty values

```
mask = df.Code == ''
df.loc[mask, 'Code'] = df[mask].State.map(state_code_dict)

mask = df.State == ''
df.loc[mask, 'State'] = df[mask].Code.map({v:k for k,v in state_code_dict.items()})

    State   Code
0   Alabama AL
1   Alaska  AK
2   Arizona AZ
3   Arkansas    AR
4   Iowa    IA
5   Hawaii  HI
6   Idaho   ID
7   Alabama AL
8   Iowa    IA
9   Alaska  AK
10  Arizona AZ
```

Answer (score 4):

You can replace blank strings with `np.nan` and then use `fillna` with `pd.Series.map`. Similar idea to @RafaelC but implemented differently.

```
code_state_dict = {v: k for k, v in state_code_dict.items()}

df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df['Code'].fillna(df['State'].map(state_code_dict), inplace=True)
df['State'].fillna(df['Code'].map(code_state_dict), inplace=True)

print(df)

       State Code
0    Alabama   AL
1     Alaska   AK
2    Arizona   AZ
3   Arkansas   AR
4       Iowa   IA
5     Hawaii   HI
6      Idaho   ID
7    Alabama   AL
8       Iowa   IA
9     Alaska   AK
10   Arizona   AZ
```

Answer (score 1):

To fill in the codes

```
df['Code'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Code'] if x['Code']!='' else state_code_dict[x['State']],axis=1)
```

To fill in the states

```
state_code_dict2 = {v: k for k, v in state_code_dict.items()}
df['State'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['State'] if x['State']!='' else state_code_dict2[x['Code']],axis=1)
```

Comment: Try copying and pasting it again please.